# How to assign tokenized string elements into structure members

Tags: c, csv, token, structure, file-handling

I have a program that prints elements from a CSV file as tokens. I need to assign and interpret (based on type) those elements in structure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>
/*struct output{
   const char *token;
};*/

struct ot{
    int time, var1;
    float var2;
    char var3[10];
} ot1;

int sleep()
{
    int milliseconds = 0;
    Sleep(milliseconds); // Sleep three seconds
}
/*input selection*/
int selection(){      // menu selection
    int flag = 0;
    printf("1.start/resume 4.end\n"); // input referals
    switch(getch()){    //collect input from user
    case 49: //ASCII for 1
        flag =0; //press 1 set flag to 0 means start
        break;
    case 52: //ASCII for 4
        exit(0);
        break;        //press 4, exit the program
    }
    return 1;
}
int main()
{
    /*declaring variables*/
   //struct output st1;
    struct ot ot1;
    const char *token;
    int i = 0, status;
    char s[10];
    /*opening the file in read mode*/
    FILE *the_file = fopen("sample_data.csv", "r");
    /*condition to check if it is a null file*/
    if (the_file == NULL)
    {
        perror("unable to open the file");
        exit(1);
    }
    char line[2000]; // declaring as array of characters
    status = selection();
    while (fscanf(the_file, "%s", line)!=EOF) // loop to get each lines from the file
    {
        if (kbhit()) // checking if keyboard pressed and condition 1, and 4
        {
            status = selection();
        }
        int l = atoi(line);
        token = strtok(line, ","); // to remove ',' from csv values and view then as separate tokens
        Sleep(l);
        system("cls");             // to clear screen after
        while(token != NULL){
            printf("%s\n", token);
            i++;
            if (i == 0)
                ot1.time = atoi(token);
            else if (i == 1)
                ot1.var1 = atoi(token);
            else if (i == 2)
                ot1.var2 = atof(token);
            else
                strcpy(ot1.var3,token);
            token = strtok(NULL, ",");//to continue tokenizing the current string
        }
        i=0;
        printf("\n");
        printf("%d",ot1.time);


    }
    return 0;
}
```

in this code, I tried to increment a variable 'i' and according to the change, I tried to assign the token values to the struct members. When i run the program, it is assigning to the first two variables but not the rest.

Comment: What exactly stops you from doing this? What is your code and how does it not work? Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with detailled problem description as well as input, output and expected output.

Comment: pleease wait. I'll add my code

Comment: https://github.com/DelwinMathewJoseph/csv/tree/main

Comment: I need to assign those token values to the elements in the struct

Comment: The git link will take you to the code

Comment: This is not how SO works. The (reduced) code needs to be in the question. Pleae take [the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi Gerhardh, I'm sorry as i have very less idea about SO, i did that mistake. the CSV reading part of the program along with the headers are mentioned here

Comment: Note, the non-roundabout way to write `case 49: //ASCII for 1` is `case '1':`

Comment: What input do you provide? Please show a few example lines of your CSV file.

Comment: What is this sleeping and keyboard access stuff about? Why do you spill your file parsing with such stuff?

Comment: You will never assign first value as `if (i==0) ...` won't ever be true.